# How to add item to specific index of a Map list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code I was able to remove items using an index from the list now I want to insert it into a specific index of the Map.

```
Map<String,bool> item_list = {
    " 077-231-0000": true,
    " 074-043-0000": true,
    " 077-572-0000": true,
  };

void reorderData(int oldindex, int newindex) {
    String key =  widget.item_list.keys.elementAt(oldindex);
    setState(() {
      if (newindex > oldindex) {
        newindex -= 1;
      }
      final items = widget.item_list.remove(key);
      widget.item_list.insert(newindex, items);
    });
  }
```

This is how it could be done with a string list. I want to do the same with Map.

```
final items = widget.item.removeAt(oldindex);
widget.item.insert(newindex, items);
```

Comment: use list/array for manipulation and then convert back to map !

Answer (score 2):

Dart map is not an `ordinal` dataset, because it doesn't have an `inherent order`.

However, you can do something like this:

```dart
void insert(Map<String, bool> itemsToInsert, int index) {
  var keys = item_list.keys.toList();
  var values = item_list.values.toList();

  for (var entry in itemsToInsert.entries) {
    keys.insert(index, entry.key);
    values.insert(index, entry.value);

    index++;
  }

  item_list = Map.fromIterables(keys, values);
}
```